# How do you interpret a Pearson Distribution in R using PearsonFitM()?

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a Pearson Distribution in R to determine the fitting of my data, and have downloaded the Pearson DS package required.
I am wondering how I could do this (I have calculated the mean, skewness, kurtosis, and variance), but I am unsure of how to implement this into a plot to determine the best fit for my data (and I can't find much help on the internet).
Can anyone offer insight? Thank you!

```
pearsonFitM(0.5205263, 0.45878677, skewness = 1.747905, kurtosis = 5.706342) 
#$type 
#[1] 1 
#$a 
#[1] 0.3586638 
#$b 
#[1] 2.281215 
#$location 
#[1] 0.00812575 
#$scale 
#[1] 3.771429
```

What is the output of the code meant to mean?

```
dput(head(data, 20))
structure(list(d.x = c(-0.813355132823045, -0.805220670463659,
-0.797086208104273, -0.788951745744888, -0.780817283385502, -0.772682821026116,
-0.76454835866673, -0.756413896307345, -0.748279433947959, -0.740144971588573,
-0.732010509229188, -0.723876046869802, -0.715741584510416, -0.707607122151031,
-0.699472659791645, -0.691338197432259, -0.683203735072874, -0.675069272713488,
-0.666934810354102, -0.658800347994716), d.y = c(0.00563353344249068,
0.00612526392312566, 0.00667315589517644, 0.00725668334434729,
0.00787280560953214, 0.00856092249030263, 0.00928466241833289,
0.0100591245078738, 0.0109085846500667, 0.011799816899246, 0.0127655124179447,
0.0138065570400635, 0.0148962199507774, 0.0160906784806625, 0.0173572960844283,
0.0186816838129897, 0.0201455497537709, 0.0216754899460307, 0.0232937519123975,
0.02505319714138)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

```r
library(PearsonDS)

moments <- c(mean = 0.5205263, variance = 0.45878677, skewness = 1.747905, kurtosis = 5.706342)
ppar <- pearsonFitM(moments = moments)
print(unlist(ppar))
#>       type          a          b   location      scale 
#> 1.00000000 0.35866383 2.28121495 0.00812575 3.77142950
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

COMPLETE CODE TO DETERMINE MOMEMTS (ATTEMPTING TO FIT EXISTING DATA TO PEARSON DISTRIBUTION)

```
moments <- c(mean = 0.5205263, variance = 0.45878677, skewness = 1.747905, kurtosis = 5.706342)
ppar <- pearsonFitM(moments = moments)

pearsonMoments(params=ppar) 
     mean  variance  skewness  kurtosis 
0.5205263 0.4587868 1.7479050 5.7063420
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas. Here is the output of dput(head(df,20)):

Comment: And if you have calculated the moments, can you post a more complete, reproducible example?

Comment: @Rui Barradas> moments <- c(mean = 0.5205263, variance = 0.45878677, skewness = 1.747905, kurtosis = 5.706342)
> ppar <- pearsonFitM(moments = moments)
> print(unlist(ppar))
      type          a          b   location      scale
1.00000000 0.35866383 2.28121495 0.00812575 3.77142950
> pearsonMoments(params=ppar)
     mean  variance  skewness  kurtosis
0.5205263 0.4587868 1.7479050 5.7063420

Comment: Thanks, much better. One more question, how do you compute those moments from the data? I'm not getting them, neither from `d.x` nor from `d.y`.

Comment: Maybe `curve(dpearson(x, params = ppar), from = ppar$location, to = 5)`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas The code and an explanation is listed above. Sorry for the confusion. I am just very lost with this, and no information online.

Comment: OK, I haven't explained myself properly. The numbers in `moments <- c(mean = 0.5205263, variance = 0.45878677, skewness = 1.747905, kurtosis = 5.706342)` *come from where*? `pearsonFitM` and `pearsonMoments` are almost inverse functions from one another but the original values of mean, variance, skewness and kurtosis, how have you found them? And *what is their relation to the data*, if any?

Comment: @RuiBarradas We plotted a distribution from our original data set, and calculated the mean, variance, skewness, and kurtosis of that data set. Then, we tried to fit those values to a Pearson distribution because the expected distribution was not smoothed enough. Using those values from the original data set, we were assuming we could plot a Pearson distribution that would be slightly representative of the data, while offering a better fit to the data, if that makes sense. The data that we are using for the Pearson distribution comes from the data of a density curve using d$x and d$y vectors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the code below is what the question asks for, but it does show how to fit Pearson distributions to data. The code fits a Pearson type II to `d.x` and a Pearson type I to `d.y`. Then plots both fits superimposed to a histogram.

```r
data <- 
  structure(list(
    d.x = c(-0.813355132823045, -0.805220670463659, -0.797086208104273, 
            -0.788951745744888, -0.780817283385502, -0.772682821026116, -0.76454835866673, 
            -0.756413896307345, -0.748279433947959, -0.740144971588573, -0.732010509229188, 
            -0.723876046869802, -0.715741584510416, -0.707607122151031, -0.699472659791645, 
            -0.691338197432259, -0.683203735072874, -0.675069272713488, -0.666934810354102, 
            -0.658800347994716), 
    d.y = c(0.00563353344249068, 0.00612526392312566, 
            0.00667315589517644, 0.00725668334434729, 0.00787280560953214, 0.00856092249030263, 
            0.00928466241833289, 0.0100591245078738, 0.0109085846500667, 0.011799816899246, 
            0.0127655124179447, 0.0138065570400635, 0.0148962199507774, 0.0160906784806625, 
            0.0173572960844283, 0.0186816838129897, 0.0201455497537709, 0.0216754899460307, 
            0.0232937519123975, 0.02505319714138)), 
    row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

library(PearsonDS)

mom_list <- lapply(data, empMoments)
ppar_list <- lapply(mom_list, \(m) pearsonFitM(moments = m))
lapply(ppar_list, unlist, recursive = FALSE)
#> $d.x
#>       type          a   location      scale 
#>  2.0000000  0.9875312 -0.8169822  0.1618090 
#> 
#> $d.y
#>        type           a           b    location       scale 
#> 1.000000000 0.687317059 1.156387311 0.005770023 0.020459169

old_par <- par(mfrow = c(1, 2),
               oma = c(5,4,0,0) + 0.1,
               mar = c(0,0,1,1) + 0.1)
hist(data$d.x, freq = FALSE)
curve(
  dpearson(x, params = ppar_list$d.x), 
  from = min(data$d.x), 
  to = max(data$d.x), add = TRUE)

hist(data$d.y, freq = FALSE)
curve(
  dpearson(x, params = ppar_list$d.y), 
  from = min(data$d.y), 
  to = max(data$d.y) + 0.01, 
  add = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
par(old_par)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The conventional way to assess goodness of fit to a distribution is using a [Q-Q plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot).

```
library(PearsonDS)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
##
#
moments <- lapply(data,    \(x) empMoments(x))
params  <- lapply(moments, \(x) pearsonFitM(moments=x))

gg.x <- ggplot(data, aes(sample=d.x))+
  stat_qq(distribution = qpearson, dparams=list(params=params$d.x))+
  stat_qq_line(distribution = qpearson, dparams = list(params=params$d.x), 
               linetype='dashed', color='blue')+
  labs(title='Pearson Q-Q plot - d.x', x='Sample', y='Theoretical')+
  theme_bw()
gg.y <- ggplot(data, aes(sample=d.y))+
  stat_qq(distribution = qpearson, dparams=list(params=params$d.y))+
  stat_qq_line(distribution = qpearson, dparams = list(params=params$d.y), 
               linetype='dashed', color='blue')+
  labs(title='Pearson Q-Q plot - d.y', x='Sample', y='Theoretical')+
  theme_bw()
grid.arrange(gg.x, gg.y, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Note that this approach, like the other answer, starts by calculating the empirical moments based only on your data, and then converts these to parameters in the Pearson family.

Another approach would be to calculate the parameters (including Pearson Type) directly from your data using MLE (maximum likelihood estimation).

```
params  <- lapply(data, \(x) pearsonFitML(x))
##
#   same code as above for plotting...
```

[image]

The package authors note that `pearsonFitML(...)` is "very preliminary" and you can see it fails miserably in this case.